# Set Page Title using PHP

Tags: php, title

I wish to set the title of my webpage to Ultan.me - *Whatever the post title*. I want it to display the post title. The posts are submitted to a MySQL database and the title row is called "title". Any help is appreciated with this small question.

Update:

Here is the page itself now but it doesn't display the title. Should I open the php document and connect to my database somewhere different to it's current locations?

The Code (The only necessary piece is the beginning):

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="keywords" content="Mac user Ultan Casey TheCompuGeeks UltanKC">
<title>Ultan.me - <?echo $title;?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="js/jquery.labelify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":text").labelify();
});
</script>
<style>
a {text-decoration:none}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">

<!-- Menu Start -->
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php">about me</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php">archives</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php">contact</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php">gallery</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
<!-- Menu End --> 

<img src="images/banner.png" />
<div id="content">
<div id="posts">
<?php
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root') ;
mysql_select_db ('ultankc');

if (!isset($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    die("Invalid ID specified.");
}

$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM php_blog WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't select entry from table php_blog.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $date = date("l F d Y", $row['timestamp']);

    $title = stripslashes($row['title']);
    $entry = stripslashes($row['entry']);
    $get_categories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM php_blog_categories WHERE `category_id` = $row[category]");
    $category = mysql_fetch_array($get_categories);


    ?>
<p><?php echo "<p id='post-title'><strong><a href=\"post.php?id=". $id . "\">" . $title . "</a></strong></p>"; ?><br /><br />
<div id="entry"><?php echo $entry; ?>
</div><br /><br />
<p id="date">Posted in <a href="category.php?category=<?php echo $row['category']; ?>"><?php echo $category['category_name']; ?></a> on <?php echo $date; ?></p>
</p>
<h2 id="share-title">Share This Post</h2>
<div id="social-share">
<li id="link-right"><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=
I just read <?php echo $title; ?> at http://ultan.me/post.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><center>Twitter</center></a></li>
<li id="link-left"><a href="http://digg.com/submit?url=http://ultan.me/post.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><center>Digg</center></a></li>
<br>
<li id="link-right"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://ultan.me/post.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&t=<?php echo $title; ?>"><center>Facebook</center></a></li>
<li id="link-left"><a href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post?url=http://ultan.me/post.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>
"><center>Google Buzz</center></a></li>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<h2 id="comments-title">Comments</h2>
 <div id="comment-list">
    <?php

}
$commenttimestamp = strtotime("now");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM php_blog_comments WHERE entry='$id' ORDER BY timestamp";
$result = mysql_query ($sql) or print ("Can't select comments from table php_blog_comments.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $timestamp = date("l F d Y", $row['timestamp']);
      printf("<div class='comment-ind'><p id='comments'><a id='username' href=\"%s\">%s</a> %s</p>", stripslashes($row['url']), stripslashes($row['name']), $timestamp);
    print("<p class='comments'>" . stripslashes($row['comment']) . "</p><div class='clr'><br></div></div>");

  }
?>
<div class="clr"></div>
<form id="commentform" method="post" action="process.php">

<p><input type="hidden" name="entry" id="entry" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

<input type="hidden" name="timestamp" id="timestamp" value="<?php echo $commenttimestamp; ?>">

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Name (required)" /><br />

<input type="text" name="email" id="email" title="Mail (will not be published) (required)" /><br />

<input type="text" name="url" id="url" title="Website" value="http://" /><br />

<br />
<textarea  title="Your Comment Goes Here" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit_comment" id="submit_comment" value="Add Comment" /></p>

</form>
</div>
<div id="pages">

<?php
$total_results = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM php_blog"));
$total_pages = ceil($total_results['num'] / $blog_postnumber);
if ($page > 1) {
    $prev = ($page - 1);
    echo "<a href=\"?page=$prev\">&lt;&lt;  Newer</a> ";
}
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
    if ($page == $i) {
        echo "$i ";
    }
    else {
        echo "<a href=\"?page=$i\">$i</a> ";
    }
}
if ($page < $total_pages) {
   $next = ($page + 1);
   echo "<a href=\"?page=$next\">Older &gt;&gt;</a>";
}

?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Sidebar Start -->
<div class="sidebar">

<!-- Item 1 -->
<div id="side-item"> 
<h2>
<a href="http://www.dailybooth.com/UltanCasey">
<img src="images/db-icon.jpg">Dailybooth
</a></h2>
<div id="side-item-content">
<center>
<img src="http://dailybooth.com/UltanCasey/latest/medium.jpg" />
</center>
</div>

</div>

<!-- Item 2 -->

<div id="side-item">
<h2><img src="images/connect.jpg" />Connect</h2>
</div>
<div id="side-item-content">
<div class="tweet-title"><p><a href="http://www.twitter.com/UltanKc">Latest Tweet:</a></p></div>
<div id="tweet">
<?php

function getTwitterStatus($userid){
$url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/$userid.xml?count=1";

function auto_link_twitter ($text)
{
    // properly formatted URLs
    $urls = "/(((http[s]?:\/\/)|(www\.))?(([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\.[a-z]{2,2})?)\/?[a-z0-9._\/~#&=;%+?-]+[a-z0-9\/#=?]{1,1})/is";
    $text = preg_replace($urls, " <a href='$1'>$1</a>", $text);

    // URLs without protocols
    $text = preg_replace("/href=\"www/", "href=\"http://www", $text);

    // Twitter usernames
    $twitter = "/@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/is";
    $text = preg_replace ($twitter, " <a href='http://twitter.com/$1'>@$1</a>", $text);

    // Twitter hashtags
    $hashtag = "/#([A-Aa-z0-9_-]+)/is";
    $text = preg_replace ($hashtag, " <a href='http://hashtags.org/$1'>#$1</a>", $text);
    return $text;
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("could not connect");

       foreach($xml->status as $status){
       $text = $status->text;
       }
       echo auto_link_twitter ($text);
 }


getTwitterStatus("UltanKC");

?>
</div>
<br>
<ul>
<li id="social"><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
<li id="social"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
<li id="social"><a href="#">LastFM</a></li>
<li id="social"><a href="#">Email</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
<!-- Item 2 End-->
<div id="side-item">
<h2><img src="images/archive.jpg" />Archives</h2>
</div>
<div id="archive-side">
<?php
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root') ;
mysql_select_db ('ultankc');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%Y') AS get_year, COUNT(*) AS entries FROM php_blog GROUP BY get_year");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $get_year = $row['get_year'];
    $entries = $row['entries'];

    echo "<li id='tag'><a href=\"archives.php?year=" . $get_year . "\">Entries from " . $get_year . "  (" . $entries . ")<br /></a></li>";
}

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM php_blog_categories ORDER BY category_name ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS entries FROM php_blog WHERE category = $row[category_id]");
    $num_entries = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

    echo '<li id="tag"><a href="category.php?category=' . $row['category_id'] . '">' . $row['category_name'] . ' (' . $num_entries['entries'] . ')</a></li>';

}
?>
</div>

</div>

<div class="clr" />
</div>
<!-- Sidebar End  -->
<div id="footer">
<p> &copy; Ultan Casey 2010</p>
<p style="margin-top: -18px; float:right"><a href="index.php">Home</a> | <a href="about.php">About Me</a> | <a href="mailto:ultankc@thecompugeeks.com">Email Me</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
?>
```

Answer (score 26):

Here's the method I use (for similar things, not just title):

```
<?
ob_start (); // Buffer output
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title><!--TITLE--></title>
</head>

<body>
<?
$pageTitle = 'Title of Page'; // Call this in your pages' files to define the page title
?>
</body>
</html>
<?
$pageContents = ob_get_contents (); // Get all the page's HTML into a string
ob_end_clean (); // Wipe the buffer

// Replace <!--TITLE--> with $pageTitle variable contents, and print the HTML
echo str_replace ('<!--TITLE-->', $pageTitle, $pageContents);
?>
```

PHP usually works be executing any bits of code and printing all output directly to the browser. If you say `"echo 'Some text here.';"`, that string will get sent the browser and is emptied from memory.

What output buffering does is say "Print all output to a buffer. Hold onto it. Don't send ANYTHING to the browser until I tell you to."

So what this does is it buffers all your pages' HTML into the buffer, then at the very end, after the  tag, it uses ob_get_contents () to get the contents of the buffer (which is usually all your page's HTML source code which would have been sent the browser already) and puts that into a string.

ob_end_clean () empties the buffer and frees some memory. We don't need the source code anymore because we just stored it in $pageContents.

Then, lastly, I do a simple find & replace on your page's source code ($pageContents) for any instances of '' and replace them to whatever the $pageTitle variable was set to. Of course, it will then replace `<title><!--TITLE--></title>` with Your Page's Title. After that, I echo the $pageContents, just like the browser would have.

It effectively holds onto output so you can manipulate it before sending it to the browser.

Hopefully my comments are clear enough.
Look up ob_start () in the php manual ( http://php.net/ob_start ) if you want to know exactly how that works (and you should) :)

Comment: Since you are going through all of this trouble anyway, why not simply use a templating engine, such as Smarty?

Answer (score 7):

You parse the field from the database as usual.

Then let's say you put it in a variable called `$title`, you just

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ultan.me - <?php echo htmlspecialchars($title);?></title>
</head>
```

EDIT:

I see your problem. You have to set `$title` BEFORE using it. That is, you should query the database before `<title>...`

Comment: When I attempt that the area after "Ultan.me -" is blank. I haven't opened the PHP at the very beginning of the document. Should I?

Comment: short tags is weird practice

Comment: What zerkms is trying to say, is you should use <?php echo $myvar;?> instead of <? echo....

Comment: @Matt Williamsonah, now I get it. BTW I didn't know.

Answer (score 4):

**header.php** has the title tag set to `<title>%TITLE%</title>;` the "%" are important since hardly anyone types %TITLE% so u can use that for str_replace() later. then, you use output buffer like so

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("header.php");
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$buffer=str_replace("%TITLE%","NEW TITLE",$buffer);
echo $buffer;
?>
```

For more reference, click [PHP - how to change title of the page AFTER including header.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009227/php-how-to-change-title-of-the-page-after-including-header-php)

Answer (score 3):

What about using something like:

```
<?php 
    $page_title = "Your page tile";
    include("navigation.php");             // if required
    echo("<title>$page_title</title>");
?>
```

Comment: This worked for me doing just echo `"<tittle>YadaYadaYada</title>"` which is exactly what I needed to get raw pages/tabs an easy way to stand out on my browser even if they don't have any html in them.

Answer (score 2):

Move the data retrieval at the top of the script, and after that use:

```
<title>Ultan.me - <?php echo htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></title>
```

Comment: When I attempt that the area after "Ultan.me -" is blank. I haven't opened the PHP at the very beginning of the document. Should I?

Comment: @klez: so? he will think up this himself.

Comment: @ThatMacLad: we have no idea what you mean. try be more detailed.

Comment: I'll update the post itself with the beginning of my php document so that it can be more detailed.

Comment: Added. The only necessary piece is the beginning of the document.

Comment: @ThatMacLad: move the data retrieval at the top of the script.

Comment: Where exactly should I place the data retrieval? When I move it to the very top the page is completely blank and the title area doesn't display.

Comment: @ThatMacLad: you have to learn how to program or to hire somebody to do that. no alternatives.

Comment: Oh and just FYI... I'm only 15 so you can't expect me to have a world of programming knowledge crammed into my skull. I was just looking for a small bit of help.

Comment: Your age is not a justification. If you are learning - then try to learn on a simple code samples, and if you're working - then it is an issue that you've got a work you know nothing about

Comment: @Brad: I would better specify flag and encoding

Comment: @zerkms, Encoding defaults to UTF-8, and I can't think of a situation where the default flag of `ENT_COMPAT` isn't sufficient.  To each their own... it is your post after all, I was just adding a bit to improve.

Comment: @Brad: " and I can't think of a situation where the default flag of ENT_COMPAT isn't sufficient" --- http://pastebin.com/KPSqZeQ8 and request with single quote will do the work

Comment: @zerkms, Ah, interesting.  I always use double quotes on my HTML attributes, but I can definitely see where that could cause some troubles.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the value of `$title` before echoing it.

Also, you should really sanitize any data before using it in queries as this is a security risk

Answer (score 2):

create a new page php and add this code:

```html
<?php
function ch_title($title){
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    if ( ob_get_length() > 0) { ob_end_clean(); }
    $patterns = array("/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/");
    $replacements = array("<title>$title</title>");
    $output = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements,$output);
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

in `<head>` add code: `<?php require 'page.php' ?>` and on each page you call the function `ch_title('my title');`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$title` is being referenced on line 5 before it's being assigned on line 58. Rearranging your code isn't easy, because the data is both retrieved and output at the same time. Just to test, how does [something like this work?](http://pastie.org/private/ewsnptkdirzqyyvm2xoxa)

Because you're only retrieving one row, you don't need to use a while loop, but I left it with hopes that it'll make it easier for you to relate to your current code. All I've done is removed the actual output from your data retrieval, and added variables for category and category name which are then referred to as usual later on. Also, I haven't tested this. :)

Answer (score 1):

It'll be tricky to rearrange your code to make this work, but I'll try :)

So, put this at the top of your code:

```
<?php require_once('mysql.php'); ?>
```

The top of the file should look like:

```
<?php require_once('mysql.php'); ?>
<html>
    <head>

    <meta name="keywords" content="Mac user Ultan Casey TheCompuGeeks UltanKC">
    <title>Ultan.me - <?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?> </title>
```

Then, create a file called mysql.php in the same directory that the file which contains the code you quoted is in.

Put this is mysql.php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db ('ultankc');

if (!isset($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    die("Invalid ID specified.");
}

$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM php_blog WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't select entry from table php_blog.<br />" .       $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

$date = date("l F d Y", $res['timestamp']);
$title = $res['title'];
$entry = $res['entry'];
$get_categories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM php_blog_categories WHERE `category_id` = $res['category']");
$category = mysql_fetch_array($get_categories);

?>
```

Well, hope that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but having read this I think this solution is much simpler (though technically it solves the problem with Javascript not PHP).

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Ultan.me - Unset</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setTitle( text ) {
            document.title = text;
        }
    </script>
    <!-- other head info -->
    </head>

    <?php 
    // Make the call to the DB to get the title text. See OP post for example
    $title_text = "Ultan.me - DB Title";

    // Use body onload to set the title of the page
    print "<body onload=\"setTitle( '$title_text' )\"   >";

    // Rest of your code here
    print "<p>Either use php to print stuff</p>";
    ?>
    <p>or just drop in and out of php</p>
    <?php

    // close the html page
    print "</body></html>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simply add $title variable before require function**

```
<?php
    $title = "Your title goes here";
    require("header.php");
  ?>
```

**header.php**

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo APP_TITLE?> - <?php echo $page_title;?>
```

this should work fine for you

Answer (score 0):

if you want to current script filename as your title tag

include the function in your project

```
function setTitle($requestUri)
         {
            $explodeRequestUri = explode("/", $requestUri);
            $currentFileName = end($explodeRequestUri);
            $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $currentFileName);
            $explodeCurrentFileName = explode("-", $withoutExt);
            foreach ($explodeCurrentFileName as $curFileValue) 
            {
               $fileArrayName[] = ucfirst($curFileValue);
            }
            echo implode(" ", $fileArrayName);

         }
```

and in your html include the function script
and replace your title tag with this

```
<title>Your Project Name -
            <?php setTitle($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
        </title>
```

it works on php7 and above but i dont have any idea about php 5.*
Hope it helps