# How can I give a title for each of my pages?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to give a title to each of my pages, but all my pages are linked to my `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("top_bar.php");?>
        <?php include("header.php");?>
        <?php include("container.php");?>
        <?php include("footer.php");?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is how my site is: http://prntscr.com/47nn7h

[image]

All my pages have the title I put for `index.php`, but how to add a title to a specific page (example, when I go to the page `members.php`)?

members.php:

```
<?php include "index.php";?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could build a conditional title string with PHP based on the page you are viewing. Then display that string in the `<title>` tag. How do you include specific page content? Is there a variable to indicate which page to show? (e.g. `$page='members';`)

Comment: if they are not separate pages, then you should change the title of your index accordingly

Comment: I would like the title changes automatically depending on the page where I am. I have members.php, sign_up.php, sign_in.php pages. How can I place the title for each pages?

Comment: No, I don't have. All pages are based on my index.php page. I really don't know how can I put a title for each of my pages.

Comment: I suggest reversing your logic so that all pages run off of `index.php`. Instead of including `index.php` from `members.php`, include `members.php` from `index.php` when `$page=='members'`. That way you can use `$page` to conditionally set a title string for each page.

Comment: Problem fixed, I used this method:
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "index") !== false) { ?>
<title>Test</title>
<?php } ?>

Answer (score 2):

Replace the existing `<title>` tag with this.

```
<title><?php echo $pagetitle; ?> </title>
```

in your `<head>` block.

Make sure that `$pagetitle` actually contains the desired title before you emit the tag. It's not clear from your question where these titles are coming from - you'll probably need some PHP right at the top of the page to set all this up.
.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Where I put it? In my index.php, bellow the <title> tag? Or in the specific page?

Comment: put `$pagetitle` avoe the `<title>` tag, otherwise there will be an error.

Comment: Replace the existing `<title>` tag.

Comment: Problem fixed, I used this method:
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "index") !== false) { ?>
<title>Test</title>
<?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463716/set-page-title-using-php) method and add the

```
$pageTitle = 'Title of Page';
```

to your content page (i.e. member page)

Comment: Problem fixed, I used this method:
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "index") !== false) { ?>
<title>Test</title>
<?php } ?>