# PHP metatags description and keywords dynamics

Tags: php

I want that keywords and description meta tags are wrote dynamically. I saw this [thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463716/set-page-title-using-php?rq=1) but I can't do the same for metatags. 
Here's my code: http://runnable.com/VCSYsvEy0xov2fNi/my-for-php

index.php

```
<?php
ob_start (); // Buffer output
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title><!--TITLE--></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="it" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />  
    <meta name="keywords" content="<!--KEYWORDS-->" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config/expand.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config/scriptbreaker-multiple-accordion-1.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".topnav").accordion({
            accordion:false,
            speed: 500,
            closedSign: '[+]',
            openedSign: '[-]'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="banner"><?php include('template/banner.php') ?></div>
            <!--<div id="nav_main"><?php include('template/nav_main.php') ?></div> -->
            <div id="navigation_left"><?php include("template/link_left.php") ?></div>      
            <div id="navigation_right" align="left"><?php include("template/link_right.php") ?></div>                               
            <div id="content"><?php include("$page.php") ?> </div>
            <div id="footer"><?php include('template/footer.php') ?></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$pageContents = ob_get_contents (); // Get all the page's HTML into a string
$pageKeywords = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean (); // Wipe the buffer

// Replace <!--TITLE--> with $pageTitle variable contents, and print the HTML
echo str_replace ('<!--TITLE-->', $pageTitle, $pageContents);
echo str_replace ('<!--KEYWORDS-->', $pageKey, $pageKeywords);

?>
```

home.php (main page)

```
<?php $pageTitle = 'Full Metal Panic Italy | Home';?>
<?php $pageKey = 'full, metal, panic, fmp, fumoffu, the second raid, spoiler, mithril, amalgam, sigma';?>
<p style="background:#aaf">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetaur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
  exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
  irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
  officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

for title it works, but no for meta.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
$pageContents = ob_get_contents (); // Get all the page's HTML into a string
ob_end_clean (); // Wipe the buffer

// Replace <!--TITLE--> with $pageTitle variable contents, and print the HTML
$pageContents = str_replace ('<!--TITLE-->', $pageTitle, $pageContents);
$pageContents = str_replace ('<!--DESCRIPTION-->', $pageDesc, $pageContents);
echo str_replace ('<!--KEYWORDS-->', $pageKey, $pageContents);
```

Comment: Perfect! It works! I tried to do the same for description but it duplicates html and doesn't add description string.
echo str_replace ('<!--DESCRIPTION-->', $pageDescription, $pageContents);

Comment: don't duplicate the `echo` line that is printing out your data, if you look at your page you are actually going to have 2 full sets of data ... scroll to the bottom.  You need to do some basic intro to PHP lessons before you move forward.  To solve this duplicate the line above and do the description part.

Comment: I have already duplicate and I added 
<meta name="description" content="<!--DESCRIPTION-->" />
and yes, I have 2 sets of data

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can see how that would be achieved.

Comment: Thank you! Could explain me why were duplicating data?

Comment: you were `echo`ing (outputting) the data twice instead of storing it in a variable to replace the next part of the string.