# How to use a string as the title of a web page?

Tags: php, title

I want web page to have title of the post being viewed, just as you can see my question as title of this page. I get title from database in a sequence so don't want to run my code before `title` tag. Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463716/set-page-title-using-php) question first answers seems reliable but didn't work for me. Is there any similar way by which I can replace the title in `title` tag with code at the end of page as at that moment I have title as a sting.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the **title** dynamically only on the **page loads.**

```
<title> <?php echo $title;?> </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

paradigm shift:
do all your business logic first..   then generate the page via some sort of templating engine.

Even if it's as simple as storing a bunch of variables
$title, $body, $navigation, etc

then

```
<html>
<head>
   <title><?= $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
   <?= $navigation ?>
   <?= $body ?>
</body>
</html>
```

very simplistic example, but hopefully it gets you thinking.
This would be the first baby step to MVC / keeping your code/logic separate from your display/output